# gdevilspie doesn't work on my PC

Tags: linux, administration

[gdevilspie](http://code.google.com/p/gdevilspie/) is a tool that allows you to write rules to move windows to any position as you wish when you open them.

I have Ubuntu 11.04 with GNOME 2.32.1 on my PC.

I like the features that gdevilspie provides, but it doesn't work on my environment. I don't know why. How do I fix it? Or are there tools have the same feature?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't workable on my environment'? Does it kill your kitten, eat your pizza or splash garbage in your house? Please be specific. Check and paste any logs or error messages. Or at the very least what exactly you wrote to get it working.

Comment: it is a gui tool, no obvious output, as far as i know. currently i only suspect the gnome version. i think someone maybe have the same experience so i ask this question.

Comment: try running it from a terminal and see if it shows anything

Comment: i tried, it shows nothing.